# Dividing comma separated strings into columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have a problem with dividing comma separated values. I have 2 columns with comma separated values, for ex:

```
ID        Name 
1,2,3     Ab,cd,ef
```

I want the columns divided as:

```
Id  Name
1   ab
2   cd
3   ef
```

I used:

```
 xmltable('r/c' passing xmltype('<r><c>' || replace(ID,',','</c><c>') || '</c></r>')
          columns ID_NEW varchar2(400) path '.') <br/>
```

Output was:

```
ID      Name 
1       ab,cd,ef
2       ab,cd,ef
3       ab,cd,ef
```

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: xmltable('r/c' passing xmltype('<r><c>' || replace(ID,',','</c><c>') || '</c></r>')
                      columns ID_NEW varchar2(400) path '.')

Comment: Sorry I used tha above query to get output but its not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm using regexp_substr

```
with test as
(select '1,2,3' col1, 'Ab,cd,ef' col2 from dual)
  select regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) result1, regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) result2
  from test
  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col1, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```

This is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2145/1).

Comment: +1 This is definitely on the right path. Your SQLFiddle creates a table then doesn't use it btw. The main issue seems to me to be that it is likely that the OPs tabel has more than one row in it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4e3f1/1

Answer (score 0):

11g - the same with regexp_count()

```
WITH test AS
 (SELECT '1,2,3' col1, 'Ab,cd,ef' col2 FROM dual)
-- 
SELECT regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) result1,
       regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) result2
  FROM test
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1;
```